# Empty search causes postback and empty result set

Tags: feature-request, bug, search

If you click into the search box and hit enter, it takes you to a page with an empty set of results. Maybe this is by design, but most websites that allow you to search will either maintain the page you are on (do nothing) or do a wild card search (maybe redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/questions)

Comment: Ideally, the page should also give information on search (which isn't hidden behind *another* click)... although I'm sure it *used* to do this before, no?

Comment: @Matt we're working on a help center article that explain search (including advanced), we plan to have this linked in that vast empty space that exists now.